# Solving equations involving NIntegrate

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, functions, numerical-integration

First, I have defined some functions like

```
f1[x_,m_,o_,a_] := (x^2)*(0.5*(1 - (x^2 + ((o - m)/a))/((1 + (x^2 + ((o -
m)/a))^2)^0.5)));
f2[y_,m_,o_,a_] := -(y^2)*(0.5*(1 + ((-(y^2) + ((-o + m)/a))/((1 + (-(y^2) + ((-o + 
m)/a))^2)^0.5))));
g1[x_,m_,o_,a_] := ((x^2) - ((1 + (x^2 + ((o - m)/a))^2)^0.5))/(((1 + (x^2 + ((o - 
m)/a))^2)^0.5));
g2[y_,m_,o_,a_] := ((y^2) - ((1 + (-(y^2) + ((-o + m)/a))^2)^0.5))/(((1 + (-(y^2) + 
((-o + m)/a))^2)^0.5));
```

Then, numerical integration on these functions are set up

```
Q1[m_?NumericQ, o_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f1[x,m,o,a], {x, 0, Infinity}];
Q2[m_?NumericQ, o_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f2[y,m,o,a], {y, 0, Infinity}];
P1[m_?NumericQ, o_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[g1[x,m,o,a], {x, 0, Infinity}];
P2[m_?NumericQ, o_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[g2[y,m,o,a], {y, 0, Infinity}];
```

Now using the two equations below:

```
o == (o/a)*(P1[m,o,a] + P2[m,o,a])^-2
```

and

```
e == ((o/a) + (3*(Q1[m,o,a] + Q2[m,o,a]))^(2/3))*(P1[m,o,a] + P2[m,o,a])^-2
```

, **I want to obtain a plot of m vs o, and also a vs o (for different e)**. It seems like if I fix the values of o and e in the above equations, I can solve for m and a. 
I tried to use `NSolve` and also `FindRoot`. Mathematica is new for me and I do not properly know how to obtain my goal. 
Here is what I tried with `FindRoot`:

First, I set `o=0.2;` and `e=0.1;`. Then,

```
    FindRoot[{o == (o/a)*(P[m,o,a] + P2[m,o,a])^-2, e == ((o/a) + (3*(Q[m, o,a] + Q2[m,o,a]))^(2/3))*(P[m,o,a] + P2[m,o,a])^-2}, {{a, 0.5}, {m, 0.5}}]
```

gives me the following error

```
FindRoot::jsing: Encountered a singular Jacobian at the point {a,m} = {0.5,0.5}. Try perturbing the initial point(s).
```

but also outputs

```
{a -> 0.0403054, m -> -0.0437156}
```

**edit:** It seems like there are multiple roots. I could not find a proper way to use  `NSolve` with my equations to obtain all the roots. 
Is there some way that I can still obtain the plots that I want?

Comment: `Q1[m_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f1[x], {x, 0, Infinity}];` This definition is incorrect.  There is no explicit `m` or `a` on the right hand side.  `:=` does explicit substitution.  It does not care about any global symbols named `m` or `a`.  You need to make these parameters of `f1`.

Comment: @Szabolcs I corrected it. Any idea on how to proceed further to obtain the plots?